Convert file.s generated by llvm to and exe file
I have a .ll file and using llc I converted it to .s but when i run
clang file.s -o out it gives the following error
clang: warning: unable to find a Visual Studio installation; try running Clang from a developer command prompt [-Wmsvc-not-found]
clang: error: unable to execute command: program not executable
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I also tried gcc and gave the same result what can I do
